# How to decode a video at a certain fps using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, odroid

I am working on video decoding using FFmpeg.
When I try to decode a video which is encoded with h265 at a certain fps (ex: fps=25), the result is a decoded video but at a different fps.
How can I decode a video at exactly fps=25, even if I have a high miss rate or dropped frames?
I use this command to decode:
ffmpeg -benchmark -i  -f null /dev/null

I am running the above command on Odroid-XU3 board that contains 8 cores. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Please, any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you talking of decode speed strictly or frames sent to the null muxer?

Comment: I am talking about decoding speed, i.e. I want to decode a video of 10s in 10s, even with old hardware, despite, of course, the bad quality (dropped frames, miss rate).

Answer (score 0):

You can add ‘-re’ to the ffmpeg command lint to process in real time. Ffmpeg will not drop frames though. So if it can’t decode that fast, you will still fall behind.

Comment: I tried "-re" option but unfortunately, it didn't change anything. Did I miss something?